# Difference between MinGW and the regular GCC?

Tags: gcc, mingw

On the SourceForge page for MinGW, you can download the GCC 4.5.2 and that's the latest version.  On the GNU mirrors, you can download the GCC 4.6 source and compile it with one of the possible windows targets:

```
i[3456789]86-w64-mingw*
i[3456789]86-*-mingw*
x86_64-*-mingw*
```

Is there a difference between using one of these targets and the traditional GCC for MinGW?  Would it make sense to use the regular GCC because it has more up-to-date versions or would it make more sense to wait until an up-to-date GCC for MinGW is released?

Comment: MinGW is for compatibility with Windows. MinGW uses GCC/G++, and MinGW is not a compiler, it's basically a stripped version of Cygwin that uses MS libs wherever possible.

Comment: Also, GCC doesn't really change. Any version will probably do. C hasn't changed in years, so there's not much to worry about.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the version of the GCC that is packaged with MinGW.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: tjameson: It has changed; at least, on the C++ side, anyway.  Improved support for C++0x has been added in recent versions of the GCC, and while it's still experimental, these new features are very useful.

Comment: C++ has changed, not C. When I see GCC, I assume C, when I see G++, I assume C++, even though G++ is basically an alias for GCC. What language are you compiling, btw? That will have an impact on whether you should wait.

Comment: @tjameson You need to distinguish between MinGW and MSYS. According to their website, "MinGW provides a complete Open Source programming tool set which is suitable for the development of native MS-Windows applications, and which do not depend on any 3rd-party C-Runtime DLLs." The compilers of course are the most important part of that. MSYS, meanwhile, is the stripped-down Cygwin fork that you mention. It "provides a general purpose command line environment, which is particularly suited to use with MinGW, for porting of many Open Source applications to the MS-Windows platform".

Comment: @ak2 - That isn't what I mean. Cygwin provides the compatibility layer for Windows so Linux applications can interface with it. The shell is a different beast. When I say stripped-down, I mean it doesn't have a lot of the wrappers that Cygwin has. It's pretty much a simple conversion between Linux APIs and Windows APIs. The command line environment is superfluous.

Comment: @tjameson: MinGW is not a conversion between Linux and Windows APIs. MinGW provides a compiler and some necessary tools to produce native Windows executables, i.e. executables that run without the need of a third-party runtime library, but use the available Microsoft C-runtime. To this end it provides headers and import libraries for the Windows system libraries. ak2 is right, what you're talking about is MSYS, which is mainly intended to be used to build software packages that make use of the automated build systems that are 'standard' on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the README file accompanying the MinGW release of GCC on SourceForge, no local patches were used, and I think this has been the case for quite a while now, so assuming there were no changes in the GCC codebase that require new local patches, you can very well download the GCC sources from one of the mirrors and build them yourself.

I have done so myself in the past, especially because I use gfortran, which is under quite heavy development, so from time to time I take the most recent snapshot and build that myself, so I can use certain new features that were only recently introduced.

(I have to admit that it took some trying to get the build to run without errors, and after a period without problems, I recently ran into some new ones that I couldn't completely smooth out. I will have to try again soon.)